# How can I download a whole mailbox from Thunderbird to a local folder?

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I am trying to back up a whole mail server to a local folder in Thunderbird, where there are many subfolders. Thunderbird is connected over IMAP, running from a gridhost server. When I attempt to copy the whole mailbox, it might last an hour before some error occurs copying a folder, and the whole process stops. I can't control the server and can't see any good reason for faults, but the error is generally along the lines of 'folder already exists'. It might be timing or something else, but I just can't get the whole mailbox to copy without errors.

Is this a known problem and are there any solutions?

Comment: If Thunderbird has already downloaded all mail, they are kept in the user's profile, e.g., C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Roaming\\Thunderbird\\Profiles in Windows, in folders *Mail* and *ImapMail*. These may or may not be *encrypted*. depending on Thunderbird settings. If *not* encrypted, you can access all messages there.

Comment: See if this works for you : [How to Access IMAP Inbox Offline in Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.lifewire.com/offline-imap-email-inbox-thunderbird-1173086).